# Keep getting Type_Error in Python when trying to solve with formula containing >

Tags: python, xml, database, function, import

I need to print all the values from XML data that are more than the average. I figured out how to solve for the average but I'm having trouble printing all the values that are more than the average. This is the code, the formula is in the more_than_average function

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET


def load_data(fpath="properties.xml"):
    tree = ET.parse(fpath)
    root = tree.getroot()

    prop_list = []

    for child in root:
        data = child.attrib.copy()
        data['netIncome'] = float(child.text)
        data["id"] = data["id"]
        data['cost'] = float(data['cost'])
        data['downPayment'] = float(data['downPayment'])
        data['state'] = data['state']
        data['percentage'] = float(data['percentage'])
        prop_list.append(data)

    return prop_list

def more_average_income(prop_list):
    value = 0
    for i in prop_list:
        value += i['netIncome']
        average = {round(value / len(prop_list), 2)}
        more_aver_inc = (value > average)
        print(more_aver_inc)
```

This is a sample of the data being imported

```
<properties>
    <property id="H00001" cost="106000"  downPayment="24380" state="NM" percentage="0.12">2925.6</property>
    <property id="H00002" cost="125000"  downPayment="30000" state="AZ" percentage="0.15">4500</property>
    <property id="H00003" cost="119000"  downPayment="24990" state="NH" percentage="0.13">3248.7</property>
    <property id="H00004" cost="124000"  downPayment="31000" state="MI" percentage="0.19">5890</property>
    <property id="H00005" cost="143000"  downPayment="34320" state="CZ" percentage="0.11">3775.2</property>
    <property id="H00006" cost="139000"  downPayment="30580" state="VI" percentage="0.12">3669.6</property>
    <property id="H00007" cost="132000"  downPayment="26400" state="ND" percentage="0.19">5016</property>
    <property id="H00008" cost="134000"  downPayment="26800" state="CZ" percentage="0.17">4556</property>
    <property id="H00009" cost="143000"  downPayment="34320" state="PA" percentage="0.14">4804.8</property>
    <property id="H00010" cost="123000"  downPayment="25830" state="IN" percentage="0.2">5166</property>
    <property id="H00011" cost="116000"  downPayment="24360" state="IL" percentage="0.09">2192.4</property>
    <property id="H00012" cost="150000"  downPayment="36000" state="OR" percentage="0.11">3960</property>
    <property id="H00013" cost="117000"  downPayment="23400" state="VI" percentage="0.19">4446</property>
    <property id="H00014" cost="116000"  downPayment="26680" state="SC" percentage="0.16">4268.8</property>
</properties>
```

I keep getting this Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/school/VisualStudio/01.LESSON/properties.py", line 77, in <module>
    funct(data)
  File "/Users/school/VisualStudio/01.LESSON/properties.py", line 59, in more_average_income
    more_aver_inc = (value > average)
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'set'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

average is a [set()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)

By surrounding your value with brackets, you are creating a set containing one value.
Python cannot compare float and set, that's why it throws an error.

```
average = round(value / len(prop_list), 2)
```

Comment: Hey thanks! How should I re write it in order for it to excute?

Comment: You can avoid the error by removing the brackets like I did in my snippet.

Comment: oh ok, I see. thanks for clarifying with an example. It's not giving an output anymore but now it's printing true instead of the value, would you know why?

Comment: You are comparing the two values. ``more_aver_inc`` will be either True or False. To print the value if it's more than the average, use a condition: ``if more_aver_inc: print(value)``